# Всплывающая подсказка на jQuery (tooltip)

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

И так, есть tooltip, который превращает атрибут title в блок и делает его кастомным.

JQ:

```
$.fn.nwfTooltip = function (showTime, hideTime) {
    $(this).each(function (i, a) {
        if (!$(a).attr('title')) return;
        a.nwfTooltipTitle = $(a).attr('title');
        $(a).attr('title', '').bind({
            mouseover: function (evt) {
                if ($('.nwf-tooltip').size() > 0) return;
                $('.nwf-tooltip').remove();
                $('<div class="nwf-tooltip" style="top:' + (evt.pageY + 15) + 'px; left:' + (evt.pageX + 10) + 'px; display: block; opacity: 0;">' + a.nwfTooltipTitle + '</div>').appendTo('body').animate({
                    top: (evt.pageY + 10) + 'px',
                    opacity: 1.0
                }, showTime);
            },
            mouseout: function () {
                $('.nwf-tooltip').fadeOut(hideTime, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
$(function () {
    $('*[title]').nwfTooltip(100, 50);
});
```

CSS:

```
.nwf - tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: #c1321d;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    max - width: 250px;
}
```

Тултип появляется в месте, где была наведена мышка, но не двигается за ней, если область большая (т.е. вообще не двигается, а на большой области это плохо смотрится). Как сделать, чтобы тултип ездил вместе с курсором?

P.S. Я в jQuery полный 0, поэтому ссылки на документацию и т.п. мне не помогут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант - http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/E7jq4/2/.

**JS**

```
$.fn.nwfTooltip = function(showTime,hideTime){
    if(!$(this).attr('title')) { return; }
    var tooltipTitle, posTop, posLeft, titleTxt;
    var tooltipBlock = '<div class="nwf-tooltip">' + tooltipTitle + '</div>';
    $(this).mouseover(function(e){
        posTop = e.pageY;
        posLeft = e.pageX;
        titleTxt = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).attr('title','');
        $(tooltipBlock).text(titleTxt).appendTo('body').css({
            top: posTop,
            left: posLeft
        }).fadeIn(showTime);

        $(document).on('mousemove',function(evt){
            if($('.nwf-tooltip').css('display') == 'block'){
                $('.nwf-tooltip').css({
                    left: evt.pageX,
                    top: evt.pageY
                });
            }
        });
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).attr('title',titleTxt);
        $('.nwf-tooltip').fadeOut(hideTime, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
};
$(function(){
    $('*[title]').nwfTooltip(400,200);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. А что, если есть просто title, но он пустой? Тогда квадратик начинает бегать. Как избавиться от такого? В моем примере такого не было.
P.s. Двиг генерит картинки в таком виде вот и не красота получается: <img src="bla.png" alt="" title>

Comment: Вторую строчку в коде:

    if(!$(this).attr('title')) { return; }

Замените на:

    if(!$(this).attr('title') || $(this).attr('title') == "") { return; }

И перенасите её сразу после строки 

    $(this).mouseover(function(e){